# Cleaning up an Iterable when not all elements are read

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, java-6

Getting my feet wet on RxJava. I have a class that implements `Iterable` I want to convert to an `Observable`. Using `Observable.from()` seems easy. However I need to setup and tear-down the code that provides me the individual entries (the `next()` in the iterator.

When I run through the entire sequence, that's easy. I added the call to the `hasNext()` function and when there is no next I run the teardown. However one of the very promising operators I want to use is `take(someNumber)`. If the taking stops before the Iterator runs out of items, the cleanup code never runs.

What can I do to get my cleanup running? If using something else than `from(Iterable)`, I'm OK with that. I'm stuck on Java6 for now. To illustrate my predicament I created a minimal sample:

**Update**: Based on feedback not to mix Iterator and Iterable together, I updated the code below. To understand the original answers, the [original code is in that gist](https://gist.github.com/Stwissel/9899999370c2741030ca75df226a4533).

Updated Test code (still bad):

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.functions.Action0;
import rx.functions.Action1;

/**
* @author stw
*
*/
public class RXTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ComplicatedObject co = new ComplicatedObject();
  Observable<FancyObject> fancy = Observable.from(co);
  // if the take is less than the elements cleanup never
  // runs. If you take the take out, cleanup runs
  fancy.take(3).subscribe(
      new Action1<FancyObject>() {

        public void call(FancyObject item) {
            System.out.println(item.getName());
        }
    },
    new Action1<Throwable>() {

        public void call(Throwable error) {
            System.out.println("Error encountered: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    },
    new Action0() {

        public void call() {
            System.out.println("Sequence complete");
        }
    }

      );

}

}
```

The fancy object:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
* @author stw
*
*/
public class FancyObject  {
private String name = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
private Date created = new Date();
public String getName() {
  return this.name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}
public Date getCreated() {
  return this.created;
}
public void setCreated(Date created) {
  this.created = created;
}
}
```

The iterator:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * @author stw
 *
 */
public class FancyIterator implements Iterator<FancyObject> {

  private final ComplicatedObject theObject;
  private int fancyCount = 0;


  public FancyIterator(ComplicatedObject co) {
    this.theObject = co;
  }

  public boolean hasNext() {
    return this.theObject.hasObject(this.fancyCount);
   }


   public FancyObject next() {
     FancyObject result = this.theObject.getOne(this.fancyCount);
     this.fancyCount++;  
     return result;
   }

}
```

The Iterable:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 * @author stw
 *
 */
public class ComplicatedObject implements Iterable<FancyObject> {

  private boolean isInitialized = false;

  Vector<FancyObject> allOfThem = new Vector<FancyObject>();


  public Iterator<FancyObject> iterator() {
   return new FancyIterator(this);
  }

  public boolean hasObject(int whichone) {
    if (!this.isInitialized) {
      this.setupAccesstoFancyObject(); 
    }
    return (whichone < this.allOfThem.size());
  }
  public FancyObject getOne(int whichone) {
      if (!this.isInitialized) {
        this.setupAccesstoFancyObject();
      }
      if (whichone < this.allOfThem.size()) {
        return this.allOfThem.get(whichone);
      }
      // If we ask bejond...
      this.isInitialized = false;
      this.teardownAccessToFancyObjects();
      return null;
  }

  private void setupAccesstoFancyObject() {
    System.out.println("Initializing fancy objects");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      this.allOfThem.addElement(new FancyObject());
    }
    this.isInitialized = true;
  }

  private void teardownAccessToFancyObjects() {
    System.out.println("I'm doing proper cleanup here");

  }

}
```

But the **real question** (thx @Andreas) seem to be:

What construct can I use to create an `Observable` when the underlying code need setup/teardown, especially when one expects that not all elements are pulled. The `Iterable` just was my first idea

**Update 2**: Based on Dave's answer I [created a gist](https://gist.github.com/Stwissel/58d27d2a463ed9adeb4039ff3a5aa0da) with my working solution. The iterator isn't perfect, but it's a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable.using` is used for tearing down on termination (completion or error) or unsubscription. To use it you need to make the tear-down code accessible so that your source observable can look like this:

```
source = Observable.using(
    resourceFactory, 
    observableFactory, 
    resourceDisposer);
```

With your code it might look like this:

```
source = Observable.using(
    () -> new ComplicatedObject(),
    co -> Observable.from(co), 
    co -> co.tearDown());
```

Comment: I presume `source` is what I subscribe to? Now I just need to translate that back to Java6 ;-)

Comment: Yep. Will be `Observable<FancyObject>`. By the way Eclipse >=4.5 will autoconvert to anonymous classes with right mouse. What IDE?

Comment: Vintage Eclipse matching the vintage Java - but I should learn with a current Eclipse version. I'm not a fan of anonymous functions. Rather have them named to keep things readable (and debuggable)

Comment: Yep I know what you mean!

Answer (score 2):

If you want that kind of control you need to separate the implementation of `Iterable` from `Iterator`.  `Iterable` means the class can provide an `Iterator` that is meaningful in whatever fashion makes sense for the class.

However, if you implement `Iterator` in the same class, then you are stuck with only ever having one `Iterator` for each instance of `ComplicatedObject`.  The correct approach is to implement

```
class FancyObjectIterator implements Iterator<FancyObject>
{
    ...
}
```

separately from `ComplicatedObject` so you can merely discard the partially-used iterators when you are done with them.  `ComplicatedObject` should implement only `Iterable<FancyObject>`.

If you object to that approach because the iterator has more state that needs special cleanup, then something is wrong with your design.  The only state an `Iterator` should be aware of is the current position in the base "collection", for a very loose definition of "collection" and "position" since the concept of an iterator can apply to much more than typical collections.

Comment: Hi Jim, thx for the reply. I lumped together Iterator and Iterable for the minimal example. I can separate it out. And yes - my design is probably wrong ;-). What I'm trying to solve is: I have a connection to something that needs setup and teardown. How do I design it so I can cleanup when my subscriber had enough rather I run out of items

Comment: @stwissel You don't use `Iterator` to traverse something that needs cleanup. `Iterable` and `Iterator` are for something that can be traversed multiple times, which implies that they work off in-memory structures.

Comment: Hi Andreas, ok, so if Iterable is out for an Observable creation that needs cleanup, what are my options?

Comment: @stwissel What does "out for an Observable creation" mean?

Comment: @Andreas: Sorry for not being clear. What I meant to say: If creating/using an Iterable that would need setup/teardown is not a good idea, then I need something else to create my Observable. My objective is an Observable. I'm open to any sensible way to get there. Observable.from(Iterable) looked like a potential way to get there - until you explained why it isn't that great (Happy to learn)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implement `Iterator` and `Iterable` at the same time, since `Iterable.iterator()` must return a *new* `Iterator` or every call.

Code is allowed to iterate the same `Iterable` multiple times in parallel.

Example: An over-simplified way to find duplicate elements in an `Iterable`:

```
Iterable<MyObject> myIterable = ...;
for (MyObject myObj1 : myIterable) {
    for (MyObject myObj2 : myIterable) {
        if (myObj1 != myObj2 && myObj1.equals(myObj2)) {
            // found duplicate
        }
    }
}
```

The enhanced `for` loops used here will each use an `Iterator`.

As you can see, each `Iterator` must maintain it's own independent position. Therefore, the `iterator()` method needs to return a new object, with it's own state.

And for your question on cleanup code, an `Iterator` does not have a `close()` method. Iterator state should not require cleanup. If they absolutely must, a finalizer can do it, but finalizers may take a *very* long time to be invoked. The general recommendation for finalizers is: DON'T.

Comment: Hi Andreas, thx for the reply. Seems I need to rephrase my example so not everybody jumps on the "don't implement iterator and iterable together". And yes -> finalizers are not a good idea